# Tkinter image labels with same image invisible except for the last one

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The problem I'm having is that identical images (in the labels) will not show except for the final label. Here is a picture to show you what I mean. In this picture, I generated 7 cards, then generated 2. I would like the spaces that are blank to be filled with the question mark.[image: Like here]

The max number of cards that can be created ranges from 0-8. If I generate 6 cards and then generate 4 cards, I would like the cards 5-6 to turn back into the random card image.

## CARD CLASS

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
class Card:
    def __init__(self, name, imageURL, cardType, rarity):
        self.name = name
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.cardType = cardType
        self.rarity = rarity
    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def returnImage(self):
        self.timage = Image.open(self.imageURL)
        if not self.timage.size == (212,263):
            self.timage = self.timage.resize((212,263), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.tphoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.timage)
        return self.tphoto
    def createLabel(self, parent):
        self.timage = Image.open(self.imageURL)
        if not self.timage.size == (212,263):
            self.timage = self.timage.resize((212,263), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.tphoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.timage)
        self.cardLabel = tk.Label(parent, image = self.tphoto)
        self.cardLabel.image = self.tphoto
        return self.cardLabel
```

## MAIN

```
randomUnknown = Card("RANDOM", PATH + '\\random-unknown.png', 'N/A', 'N/A')
#Note: randomUnknown is in a separate file. The card.randomUnknown just calls it
randomCard = card.randomUnknown

card1 = randomCard
card2 = randomCard
card3 = randomCard
card4 = randomCard
card5 = randomCard
card6 = randomCard
card7 = randomCard
card8 = randomCard

card1Label = card1.createLabel(root)
card2Label = card2.createLabel(root)
card3Label = card3.createLabel(root)
card4Label = card4.createLabel(root)
card5Label = card5.createLabel(root)
card6Label = card6.createLabel(root)
card7Label = card7.createLabel(root)
card8Label = card8.createLabel(root)
```

This is at the top of my code after the window is created. Each of the labels appear correctly with the image I am trying to display. Like so Here: [image: At the Start]

## MY ATTEMPT

Every time the button is pressed, the cards are picked and displayed. This code also runs. I have also tried setting the labels to randomCard.createLabel(root) but the same thing happened.

```
def randomizeButton():
    global currentCards,card1Label, card2Label,card3Label,card4Label,card5Label,card6Label,card7Label,card8Label
    currentCards = maxCards
    setMax()
    randomizeCards()
    print('Current Cards: ' + str(currentCards))
    if(maxCards == 0):
        card1Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card2Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card3Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card4Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card5Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 1):
        card2Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card3Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card4Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card5Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 2):
        card3Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card4Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card5Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 3):
        card4Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card5Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 4):
        card5Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 5):
        card6Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 6):
        card7Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
    if(maxCards == 7):
        card8Label.configure(image = randomCard.returnImage())
```

The labels are set in a grid.

```
card1Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
card2Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
card3Label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
card4Label.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
card5Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
card6Label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
card7Label.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
card8Label.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
```

If you need anymore information I'll be glad to supply it. I tried to give all the necessary information.

Comment: could you put the whole code? I don't get how many files... and could you explain what you want that happens in brief?

Comment: @GiovanniGianni I would like to get the labels with the '?' in them to appear in all blank spaces in the top picture. Right now, the images only appear for the last label. The whole code is about 700 lines or so and I'm fairly sure the problem is in these code snippets. Are you sure?                                          Edit: I have around 70 images

Comment: Can you provide the code for `randomCard.returnImage()`? I think that could be causing it...

Comment: @GiovanniGianni I found a work-around but I don't think it is the best way. I can create 8 different images with the '?' in it with different names and they will properly appear.

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 It is in the card class. I also added more clarification in the main class.

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 I've discovered the cause of the problem is that the '?' image in each of the labels is the same picture. I tried making a separate image for each of the labels and it worked, but I don't know why it will only work for the last label (as seen in the first image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter only allows each image instance to be used once. To display the same image multiple times, you need to load the image separately for each label.

For example, if you were trying to display the same image 5 times, you would need to run the code like so:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
image1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=icon.gif)
label1 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image1)
label1.pack()
image2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=icon.gif)
label2 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image2)
label2.pack()
image3 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=icon.gif)
label3 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image3)
label3.pack()
image4 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=icon.gif)
label4 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image4)
label4.pack()
image5 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=icon.gif)
label5 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image5)
label5.pack()
```

Obviously, this is just an example and doesn't use the variable names or classes in your code.

Comment: I decided to create different images for each of the slots instead because it worked a little bit easier for my code. Thanks anyways.